# ¿Como hallar la distancia en kilomestros entre dos coordenadas en python?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente dataframe: el cual requiere medir la distancia en kilómetros de cada uno de los datos, es decir, que requiero evaluar la distancia entre el 1 registro y los siguientes, entre el segundo registro y los siguiente y así sucesivamente.

Me puedes ayudar por favor validando como puedo realizar este proceso, muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías agregar lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora por favor? Si lo haces, tu pregunta será mejor recibida por la comunidad y asi aumentarás tu posibilidad de obtener respuestas.

Comment: Hola Dante cómo estás? Perdón realmente no tengo aún nada montado, realmente no se cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Bien! Y vos? Que te tiene trabado? Hay algo especifico?

Comment: Me refiero a que cosa no te deja pensar bien la logica del programa.

Comment: Sí necesitas calcular la distancia entre dos coordenadas, puedes utilizar la fórmula del [Semiverseno](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_del_semiverseno), la misma se calcula tomando el R (radio) de la tierra, para simplificar la fórmula se suele redondear a 6371 Kms.

Comment: Hola buenas noches, primero agradecer por sus respuestas, infinitas gracias  . Me frena en la lógica es cómo lograr en la iteración,crear en una sola fila los datos de latitud y longitud del registro 1, con los datos de latitud y longitud del registro 2 y subsiguientes registro del dataframe y así poder aplicar la fórmula que menciona Lucas. No se si me hago entender. De nuevo muchas gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí entendí bien tu planteo, lo que necesitas es calcular la distancia de cada uno de los registros, es decir, un "todos contra todos".

- **Distancia:**

Para calcular la distancia, se puede utilizar la fórmula del Semiverseno, como te había sugerido en el comentario. Consiste en tomar dos puntos de una esfera y conociendo su radio, puedes calcular la distancia que hay entre cada extremo. Cada punto (*P*) esta compuesto por una tupla (*latitud*, *longitud*) y ajustaremos *R*= 6371 (radio de la esfera/tierra) [¿Cuál es el radio de la tierra?](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_terrestre)

Fórmula:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez conocida la expresión, podemos utilizar *numpy* para llegar al objetivo *d*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    
    
    lon1 = np.radians(lon1.astype(float))
    lat1 = np.radians(lat1.astype(float))
    lon2 = np.radians(lon2.astype(float))
    lat2 = np.radians(lat2.astype(float))

    r = 6371
    
    
    dlon = np.subtract(lon2, lon1)
    dlat = np.subtract(lat2, lat1)

    a = np.add(np.power(np.sin(np.divide(dlat, 2)), 2),
               np.multiply(np.cos(lat1),
                           np.multiply(np.cos(lat2),
                                       np.power(np.sin(np.divide(dlon, 2)), 2))
                           )
              )
    c = np.multiply(2, np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a)))

    return c*r
```

Generar dataframe con valores aleatorios similares:

```
lat = np.random.uniform(3.41, 3.42, 10)
lon = np.random.uniform(-76.53, -76.54, 10)

n=10
range_end = (10**n)-1
range_start = 10**(n-1)
codigos = np.random.randint(low=range_start,high=range_end,size=10)

df = pd.DataFrame(data = zip(codigos,lat,lon),columns=['codigo','latitud','longitud'])
```

El df generado:

| codigo | latitud | longitud |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1442332394 | 3.419911 | -76.537958 |
| 6549173149 | 3.418448 | -76.534734 |
| 1421383833 | 3.411320 | -76.536033 |
| 7294226367 | 3.410781 | -76.539065 |
| 2255690678 | 3.410284 | -76.537815 |
| 2123153137 | 3.410236 | -76.533521 |
| 9523594100 | 3.415621 | -76.533819 |
| 4416155522 | 3.412395 | -76.536306 |
| 7566662267 | 3.413345 | -76.531701 |
| 6054506402 | 3.418029 | -76.536766 |

Ahora podemos hacer la iteración por código, y evaluar cada coordenada con la del código en cuestión. La parte de *pandas* estoy seguro que se puede optimizar
Definimos un dataframe resultante, que es el que va a tener todos los registros analizados con la distancia y el codigo asociado a las coordenadas consultadas

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame([])
for codigo in codigos:
    print(codigo)
    #Tomamos todos los valores menos el codigo a buscar
    aux = df[df['codigo']!=codigo]
    #Tomamos el código a buscar
    row = df[df['codigo']==codigo]
    #Asignamos una columna con el valor del código para tener en la misma fila el código consultado.
    aux['codigo_consultado'] = codigo
    
    #definimos la columna distancia en la que vamos a asignar el resultado de haber aplicado la función al df.
    aux['distancia'] = aux.apply(lambda fila: haversine(row.longitud.iloc[0],
                                                    row.latitud.iloc[0],
                                                    fila['longitud'],
                                                    fila['latitud']),
                             axis=1)
    #Agregamos el dataframe reducido a nuestro dataframe resultante.
    df_result = df_result.append(aux)
```

Llegando al resultado final: `df_result.head(10)`

| codigo | latitud | longitud | codigo_consultado | distancia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6549173149 | 3.418448 | -76.534734 | 1442332394 | 0.393083 |
| 1421383833 | 3.411320 | -76.536033 | 1442332394 | 0.978876 |
| 7294226367 | 3.410781 | -76.539065 | 1442332394 | 1.022680 |
| 2255690678 | 3.410284 | -76.537815 | 1442332394 | 1.070568 |
| 2123153137 | 3.410236 | -76.533521 | 1442332394 | 1.183179 |
| 9523594100 | 3.415621 | -76.533819 | 1442332394 | 0.662264 |
| 4416155522 | 3.412395 | -76.536306 | 1442332394 | 0.855656 |
| 7566662267 | 3.413345 | -76.531701 | 1442332394 | 1.007600 |
| 6054506402 | 3.418029 | -76.536766 | 1442332394 | 0.247596 |
| 1442332394 | 3.419911 | -76.537958 | 6549173149 | 0.393083 |

Comment: Hola Lucas.  Mil y Mil gracias por la ayuda, si es justamente lo que requiero hacer.  De nuevo mil gracias